# Instantiate a private class from java main function

Tags: java, static, this, private, public

I am not understanding why Java is giving me this error message that I am somehow referencing 'this' when I am simply trying to instantiate an inner class.
[image]

Comment: change `public class Statement` to `public static class Statement`

Comment: If I do that, won't I not be able to instantiate it?

Comment: Yes you can. Just try :)

Comment: But then I end up with a static class when I need instances. Also, I need my mother class to be abstract, do how do I make a constructor when I cannot make a static abstract class?